# How do I set up this formset in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm trying to build a form for scheduling a single (or double) elimination tournament.  For example, consider a league which has teams TeamA, TeamB, TeamC, and TeamD (all of which are already defined in my database).

The form should look something like

```
Style: choice field - {single or double elimination}
Seed1: choice field - {TeamA or TeamB or TeamC or TeamD}
Seed2: choice field - {TeamA or TeamB or TeamC or TeamD}
Seed3: choice field - {TeamA or TeamB or TeamC or TeamD}
Seed4: choice field - {TeamA or TeamB or TeamC or TeamD}
```

This is what I have...

```
class EliminationForm(Form):
    """
    Form for generating an elimination structure of Game instances
    """

    choices = [(1, "Single Elimination"), (2, "Double Elimination")]
    style = ChoiceField(choices=choices, widget=Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

How would I set up this form to dynamically build the "Seed" fields for each team in the league?

Here's my models.py

```
class League(models.Model):
    league_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Team(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey('League')
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield).

It will allow you to populate the dropdowns with the teams you have in the database:

```
class EliminationForm(Form):
    """
    Form for generating an elimination structure of Game instances
    """

    choices = [(1, "Single Elimination"), (2, "Double Elimination")]
    style = ChoiceField(
        choices=choices, 
        widget=Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
    )

    seed1 = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Team.objects.all(),
    )
    seed2 = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Team.objects.all(),
    )
    seed3 = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Team.objects.all(),
    )
    seed4 = ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Team.objects.all(),
    )
```

You can also filter the objects being used to only select teams of the same league, or only teams assigned to a league etc.

You may also want to add a `__unicode__` function to the Team model to define how it is displayed in the dropdown.

```
class Team(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey('League')
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.team_name
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful but it does not solve my problem.  You've created a form with a static number of seeds (4) but a league could have any number of teams (e.g. 20 teams).  In other words, I need the number of "Seed" fields to match the number of teams in the league which could be almost anything.  That's why I think I need to use formsets.